# Testing by flipping bits makes no sense?

Tags: testing, complexity-theory

When reading [this](http://perspectives.mvdirona.com/2012/02/26/ObservationsOnErrorsCorrectionsTrustOfDependentSystems.aspx) it said

> Remember that all hardware, all firmware, and all software have faults
>   and introduce errors. Don’t trust anyone or anything. Have test
>   systems that bit flips and corrupts and ensure the production system
>   can operate through these faults – at scale, rare events are amazingly
>   common.

I don't understand. Is it possible to run any type of software if you flip bits? pointers will be incorrect and if you read for an address on a switch case (or even function call) you can start executing in no mans land. Heck, the stack could be overwritten. If your stack is gone how could you possibly recover. You can't, you have to terminate and restart again. Terminate+restart is hardly recover.

How do you 'test' a production system but forcing a part to terminate? Is this actually saying if the system is multiple CPU/systems unplug a system and see if it non unplugged system corrupts or crashes? Otherwise i don't understand what this is suppose to mean.

Answer (score 0):

I think the main point in this is of increasing system robustness - see Jeff Atwood's Coding Horror post about the [Netflix Chaos Monkey](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2011/04/working-with-the-chaos-monkey.html) that randomly takes servers down. If you know the server is going down at some point (and most will) then you start planning for that circumstance. You add redundancy where needed, you harden the code to deal with situations like this, and you do it now instead of pushing it off which is easy to do when you're not directly feeling the pain.

A tangent off of this is that not every bit change will take down the system. It may just do things like corrupt data or inter-process communications. In that case, each component in your system needs to do its own error checking and not trust that it's always going to get good data from the other components.

By having a test system that causes these kinds of faults, you have a chance to fix them as appropriate before they become a huge problem with your customers.